# Finding max of ANDing between two numbers in Python

Tags: python, logical-operators

I am a beginner to Python coding. I have two numbers A and B from user.

My problem is to find the **max(P AND Q)** where A <= P < Q <= B

I have two solutions right now for this.

**Solution 1** : # ANDing with all combinations, This solution works if combinations are less. For higher values, it throws memory exceeding error.

```
given = raw_input()
n= list(map(int,given.split()))

A = n[0]
B = n[1]

newlist = range(B+1)
# print newlist

# Finding all combinations
comb = list(itertools.combinations(newlist,2))
# print comb

# ANDing 
l = []
for i in com:
    x = i[0] & i[1]
    l.append(x)
# print l

print max(l)
```

**Solution 2**: After observing many input-outputs, when B == Odd, max(value) = B-1 and for B == Even, max(value) = B-2.

```
given = raw_input()
n= list(map(int,given.split()))

A = n[0]
B = n[1]
if B % 2 == 0:
    print (B - 2)
else:
    print (B -1)
```

According to the problem statement I am not using any ANDing for Solution 2. Still I am getting correct output.

But I am looking for much easier and Pythonic logic. Is there any other way/logic to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Your second solution is the optimal solution. But why? First, consider that a logical AND is performed on the binary representation of a number, and it is only possible to produce a number less than or equal to the smallest operand of the AND operator. For instance, `9` is represented as `1001`, and there is no number that `9` can be anded with that produces a number higher than `9`. Indeed, the only possible outputs for anding another number with 9 would be `9`, `8`, `1` and `0`. Or alternatively, the biggest result from anding `9` with a number smaller than `9`, is `9` less its least significant bit (so `8`). If you're not sure of the binary representation of a number you can always use the `bin` function. eg. `bin(9)` => `'0b1001'`.

Let's start with odd numbers (as they're the easiest). Odd numbers are easy because they *always* have a bit in the unit position. So the maximum possible number that we can get is `B` less that bit in the unit position (so `B - 1` is the maximum). For instance, `9` is represented as `1001`. Get rid of the unit bit and we have `1000` or `8`. `9 and 8 == 8`, so the maximum result is `8`.

Now let's try something similar with evens. For instance, `14` is represented as `1110`. The maximum number we can get from anding 14 with another number would be `1100` (or 12). Like with odds, we must always lose one bit, and the smallest possible bit that can be lost is the bit in 2s position. Here, we're fortunate as `14` already as a bit in the 2s position. But what about numbers that don't? Let's try `12` (represented as `1100`). If we lost the smallest bit from `12`, we would have `1000` or `8`. However, this is not the maximum possible. And we can easily prove this, because the maximum for `11` is `10` (since we have shown the maximum for an odd number is the odd number less 1).

We have already shown that the biggest number that can be produced from anding two different numbers is the bigger number less its least significant bit. So if that bit has a value of `2` (in the case of `14`), when we can just lose that bit. If that bit has a value higher than 2 (in the case of `12`), then we know the maximum is the maximum of the biggest odd number less than `B` (which is 1 less than the odd number and 2 less than `B`).

So there we have it. The maximum for an odd number is the number less 1. And the maximum for an even number is the number less 2.

```
def and_max(A, B): # note that A is unused
    if B & 1: # has a bit in the 1 position (odd)
        P, Q = B - 1, B
    else:
        P, Q = B - 2, B - 1
    # print("P = ", P, "Q = ", Q)
    return P & Q # essentially, return P
```

Note that none of this covers negative numbers. This is because most representations of negative numbers are in [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement). What this means is that all negative numbers are represented as constant negative number plus a positive number. For instance, using an 4-bit representation of integers the maximum possible number would be `0111` (or 7, `4 + 2 + 1`). Negative numbers would be represented as `-8` plus some positive number. This negative part is indicated by a leading bit. Thus `-8` is `1000` (`-8 + 0`) and `-1` is `1111` (`-8 + 7`). And that's the important part. As soon as you have `-1`, you have an all 1s bitmask which is guaranteed to lose the negative part when anded with a positive number. So the maximum for `max(P and Q)` where `A <= P < Q <= B and A < 0` is always `B`. Where `B < 0`, we can no longer lose the negative bit and so must maximise the positive bits again.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
given = raw_input()
a, b = tuple(map(int,given.split()))
print(max([p & q for q in range(a,b+1) for p in range(a,q)]))
```

Comment: no dear. you are iterating the loop. you can try if A = 7893552  and B = 789000000.Got? my constraint for A ,B are of lenght 10^18. so you can imagine what happens if B = 10^18

Comment: @Shivkumar You did not mention that `higher values` may be as large as 10^18. In addition, the list comprehension in the answer is still faster than `itertools.combinations`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    long a,b,c,ans;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        a=s.nextLong(); 
        b=s.nextLong(); 

          if(b%2==0)
          ans=b-2;
          else
          ans=b-1;   

         if(ans>=a)   
         System.out.println(ans);
         else
         System.out.println(a&b);

    }
```